# my pc wont go to sleep and I'm out of idea what to do

Tags: windows-10, sleep

I don't understand. all the setting is set to sleep after 1 minute. I checked `powercfg` requests and nothing is keeping it awake. I don't know what else to try.

Power & Sleep Settings:

[image: Power & Sleep Settings]

System Info:

[image: System Info]

I can manually put the PC to sleep. no issue there.

Comment: Try setting sleep for 5 minutes. Reset power management settings to default. Update BIOS, Power Driver and then restart and try suspend again.

Comment: Run [powercfg -energy](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5148-create-power-efficiency-diagnostics-report-windows-10-a.html) and post online the result HTML file (as HTML).

Comment: If you manually put it to sleep what happens, edit your question, don’t reply with a comment

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Task Scheduler
2. Select "Create Task..." (right part of the window)
3. Name it whatever you want
4. Go to "Triggers" tab
5. Hit "New"
6. Under "Begin the task", select "On idle" then "OK"
7. Open Notepad and paste the following, then save it with .bat extension  somewhere you will remember

   ```
   @echo off &mode 32,2 &color cf &title Power Sleep
   set "s1=$m='[DllImport ("Powrprof.dll", SetLastError = true)]"
   set "s2=static extern bool SetSuspendState(bool hibernate, bool forceCritical, bool disableWakeEvent);"
   set "s3=public static void PowerSleep(){ SetSuspendState(false, false, false); }';"
   set "s4=add-type -name Import -member $m -namespace Dll; [Dll.Import]::PowerSleep();"
   set "ps_powersleep=%s1%%s2%%s3%%s4%"
   call powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "%ps_powersleep:"=\"%"
   exit
   ```
8. Return to Task Scheduler
9. Go to "Actions" tab
10. Hit "New"
11. Under "Action", select "Start a program"
12. Under "Program/script" browse to or paste the path of the .bat script, then hit "OK"
13. Click on "OK" to save and close the remaining windows (you can close the Task Scheduler if you want)

PS: I am still testing this method, so please tell me if it works for you.

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks I just joined this community and didn't know how to do it properly.